# Typescript React app is throwing error when using the new `satisfies` operator with TS 4.9.3

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I wanted to use the new `satisfies` operator in my `Typescript React` app but it doesn't works.

here are the `package.json` and `typescript` related package details.

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        .
        .
        .
        "babel-plugin-react-require": "^3.1.3",
        "react": "^17.0.2",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
        .
        .
        .
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.16.0",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.16.10",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.4",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.16.0",
        "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.18.6",
        "@types/react": "^17.0.36",
        "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.11",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.45.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.45.0",
        "babel-loader": "^8.2.3",
        "esbuild-loader": "^2.20.0",
        "eslint": "^8.3.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
        "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "^3.5.2",
        "eslint-plugin-eslint-comments": "^3.2.0",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.4",
        "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.5.1",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.27.1",
        "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.3.0",
        "eslint-plugin-storybook": "^0.6.7",
        "typescript": "^4.9.3",
        "webpack": "^5.75.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^4.9.1",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^4.5.0",
        "webpack-merge": "^5.8.0"
    }
}
```

[image: Browser error]
[image: VS Code error]

What could be the reason?

I've upgraded all the `typescript` related packages to latest but issue is not fixed

Comment: Same here. Hope somebody posts a solution.

Answer (score 5):

It seems the problem is caused by the babel version. (But take my answer with a grain of salt, as I am still learning myself)

The satisfies operator was introduced with Typescript 4.9 and [babel supports this Typescript version since 7.20.0](https://babeljs.io/blog/2022/10/27/7.20.0).

In the release notes babel specifically mentions `@babel/plugin-transform-typescript` and `@babel/preset-typescript` working with satisfies. But the [newest version for the npm package `@babel/preset-typescript` is 7.18.6](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@babel/preset-typescript).

So it seems to me, to solve your problem you could:

- Manually install a supporting version of `@babel/preset-typescript`
- Switch to `@babel/plugin-transform-typescript`
- Wait for the npm package to be updated

Comment: `@babel/preset-typescript"` was updated, current version `7.21.0`. And it works with `satisfies`.

Don't forget to update others babel libs to latest versions!!!

Answer (score 1):

VSCode uses it's own version of Typescript. So it might use older versions which doesn't understand `satisfies` keyword.

You can:

- Upgrade your VSCode to the latest version
- Use your workspace version of typescript by selecting `Typescript: Select Typescript version...` in command palette.

Also note that you have to restart TS Server. So restart your VSCode to see the effects.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, this is not VS Code only error because it is also breaking the app as it is shown in the screenshots

Comment: Make sure you've cleared cache. Maybe deleting node_modules & yarn.lock/package-lock.json and re-installing can help. Also try using version 7.14.0 for your babel packages (instead of 7.16.x)

Answer (score 0):

Have same problem, as workaround added plugin `@babel/plugin-transform-typescript`, not instead of `@babel/preset-typescript`, but additionally.
And now it works. I doubt this plugin makes something bad, maybe add a few ms to processing time.

Maybe someone has a better solution? If someone want to reproduce, this is a repo where it reproducible https://github.com/sshmyg/frontend. Just install, update babel packages and try to use `satisfies` in any `tsx` file.